# Julia libllvm_system not defined

Tags: julia

I am trying to install the packages CUDAnative, CuArrays, and CUDAdrv in Julia.
I'm getting the following error when I write

`Pkg.build("CUDAnative")`

`LoadError: UndefVarError: libllvm_system not defined`

Any idea why?

(I am using an Asus Zephyrus G14 with Nvidia RTX 2060 and AMD Ryzen 9)

Comment: Have you setup CUDA yet?  https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/

Comment: Kindly refrain from (re)tagging this with CUDA. It plainly isn't a CUDA related programming question. libllvm_system is, unsurpsingly, part of llvm i.e. the host compiler infrastructure. See [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/llvm-loaderror-permission-denied-eacces/10941) for a possible starting point for diagnosing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've realized that `CUDAnative`, `CuArrays` and `CUDAdrv` packages are deprecated and it is enough to use `CUDA.jl` only. The problem is arising when I want to install these libraries. They downgrade `CUDA.jl` to a <1 version.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the CUDAnative docs here: https://juliagpu.gitlab.io/CUDA.jl/installation/conditional/ for details on this issue and troubleshooting steps: https://juliagpu.gitlab.io/CUDA.jl/installation/troubleshooting/.

If you continue to have this issue, please open an issue for the package on GitHub.